# With swift5 no longer works indexPathForSelectedRow is not recognized by xcode

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

With swift5 and TableView (no TableViewController), no longer works indexPathForSelectedRow is not recognized by xcode, I don't know what has changed

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedTable = dataTableWord[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: replace the tableView with the outlet name of the UITableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change on the UITableView on swift5 or Xcode.
Make sure that you have defined your UITableView variable correctly.
Or, if you're using storyboard, remove and reconnect your tableView outlet to the UITableView object on the storyboard.